# Elements set with mix-blend-mode break other element with mix-blend-mode property (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mix-blend-mode

My `h1` element loses its `mix-blend-mode` property, defaulting back to the color of white, when another element lower in the DOM has its own `mix-blend-mode` property added.

I'm having a really tough time pin pointing the source of this issue as different elements inside a `div` container seem to be breaking the `mix-blend-mode` property of the `<h1>` element (not in said container) when they themselves are given a `mix-blend-mode` property.

I can only produce this issue on Chrome when tested on Chrome and Firefox. I am only able to produce this issue on my website, not in codepen or anything similar for some reason.

Here is a draft of the [website I'm working on](https://ariffjeff.com/) (Open in Chrome!)

When you (continuously) hover over the sample video element (which plays the video, just give it a second to start), the `h1` will lose its `mix-blend-mode` property, turning to white. Which is what I don't want. I **do** want the "video" text to gain the `mix-blend-mode` property when you hover the sample video, which it already does correctly, which I think is causing the issue somehow.

(There is a lot of extra css in the css file not attached to anything as I had to strip out many HTML elements.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that I had an empty `<div>` as the first element inside my `<body></body>` acting as a background that had a `z-index` property of a negative number, or at least a non-zero value perhaps. Once I set the `z-index` of my background `<div>` to `0` or removed the `z-index` property entirely then the `mix-blend-mode` on the `h1` problem stopped occurring for good.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="bg"></div>
  ...
  ...
</body>
```

Problem CSS:

```
#bg {
  background-image: url("../img/someImage.jpg");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

I do not understand why this solved the problem as I figured out the solution by accident.